# How to pass json array as function argument in postgresql 9.6

Tags: php, json, postgresql

--Takes a json array to parse each elements as text .But it shows an error.
   --Change the type from json[] to json but not helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test(in_param json[])
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
declare 
 item text;
 arr1 text[];
 begin 
   for item in select * from json_array_elements_text(in_param ) loop
   arr1 = arr1||item;
   end loop;
return 0;
end;
$BODY$;
ALTER FUNCTION public.test(json[])
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: `json[]` almost never makes sense. You should pass a single JSON that itself is an array value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mistaken. `["a","b","c"]` cannot be cast to `json[]`. Appending square brackets (`[]`) creates a Postgres array datatype and is not self castable to a `JSON` array type

You'll receive  this if you did so.

> ERROR:  malformed array literal

Rather, define your function to accept a simple JSON type

```
create or replace function test(json_in json) ..
..
```

Now, simply quoting your sample argument `["a","b","c"]` will work

```
select  test('["a","b","c"]')
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e7ca164f97b27acb4a96c1ea12708211)

Comment: Thanks . What I want is I want to pass ["a","b","c"] as parameter value for suppose "in_param"  as the function is like :->  test(in_param json)  . Within the function there is json_array_elements_text(in_param) will parse the json obejects from "in_param"  and store as text fields.

Comment: @abhi : Is the error coming from within the function? If so, I can't help you unless you show me the function. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54863031/edit) your question and add the function definition. If not, then are you quoting the string while passing your arguments? as in `test('["a","b","c"]') `

Comment: Yes the error is coming within the function .Please help as I posted the code .

Comment: @abhi : I changed your function arguments from `json[]` to `json` and It works, Please check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c05509b3c11ff1284e3b0f0f9451956c)

Comment: it is not  working. Actually How do I rewrite the param within quotation within function that is the point here .. select test(["a","b","c"]) does not work .

Comment: @abhi : Why do you not want to use quotes? What's the problem? just using a bare parentheses is not the right syntax

Comment: Thanks I got the point.Actually this function will be called from a php page. I mistook it to test seperately. Thanks everybody for the help .

Answer (score 0):

your are trying to pass an array 
try the following

```
String t[] = { "a", "b" };

JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(mStringArray));

test(mJSONArray)
```